# It possible to use Broadcom BCM43142 Bluetooth and disable wifi interface

Tags: broadcom

Can wireless be off but bluetooth on .???

Using Ubuntu 16.04.3 )))). I think this 
broadcom have chips with 2 different driver .. i have usb wireless adapter ac1200 dlink   182 c1 running (wlan0 ) .. how too make it as primary and default wifi interfaces .. )))))))))
`***iface wlan0 inet manual***` this Will disable my wifi adapter (wl blacklisted) ..any suggestions thanks

Comment: I do not understand the problem. You choose the preferred wireless hardware in Network Manager, and simply ignore the other.

Comment: My wireless card ''combos wifi and Bluetooth '' the bcm43xx too slow .. no bios advanced settings too switch . It's possible to turn off wifi and use the Bluetooth on the same interface?!??!